# Minimising line intergral over a scalar field part 1

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I'm self teaching  myself calculus of variations, and decided to solve a problem to practice what I learned.
Say we want to find a path $y=y(x)$ in the scalar field $S(x,y)$. Therefor we wish to minimise the integral
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} S(x,y(x)) dx $$
Let's consider a seamingly simple example where $S(x,y)=y*x^2$
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} y*x^2 dx $$
Applying the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$x^2-\frac{d}{dx} 0=0$$
Therefore $x^2=0$
Which just leaves me confused, as it don't give us any information about $y(x)$
Did I do something wrong or is this a limitation of the Euler-Lagrange?
Is there a way to solve such problems?

*This question is continued [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702190/minimising-line-integral-over-a-scalar-field-part-2)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example there isn't maximum nor minimum. Let $y(x)=c$ constant
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} yx^2 dx=c\int_{x_1}^{x_2} x^2 dx$$
and take $c$ big positive or big negative.

Comment: @ Martin-Blas Perez Pin:  what if the path has specified, fixed endpoints?

Comment: @RobertLewis No big problem in *this* case: Take a parabola with a free parameter.