# Minimising line integral over a scalar field part 2

Tags: self-learning, calculus-of-variations

This is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701513/minimising-line-intergral-over-a-scalar-field) whose general point is summarised below

> Say we want to find a path $y=y(x)$ in the scalar field $S(x,y)$ that finds the extrema of of its line integral.
>   Therefore we wish to minimise the integral $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} S(x,y(x))
>   dx $$

The original question involved $S(x,y)=y*x^2$ and the Euler-Lagrange equation returned $x^2=0$ because there was no extrema.

But intuitively $S(x,y)=x^2*y^2$ should have a minimum path for almost any two point.
Applying the Euler-Lagrange:
$$\frac{dS}{dy}-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dS}{dx'})=0 $$
$$2*x^2*y-\frac{d}{dx}0=0 $$
$$x^2*y=0 $$
Which means either $x=0$ or $y(x)=0$ which continues to confuse me, as I assumed a minimum would exist. Could somebody please explain to my how the Euler-Lagrange equation behaves for the integrand being independent of the derivative of $y$?

Comment: In this case, $y(x)=0$ for all $x$ gives obviously a minimum.

Comment: What if the endpoints don't lie in the x-axis?

Comment: Then there isn't minimum. Take $y(x_1)=y_1$, $y(x_2)=y_2$, $y(x)=0$ for $x\in[x_1+\epsilon,x_2-\epsilon]$ and extend differentiably to the rest of the interval.

Comment: Found the mistake. I was formulating the integral and thus the question wrong the $dx$ should be $\sqrt(1+\dot{y}^2)dx$